# How to fix the order in which a simple shell command is parsed?

Tags: bison, context-free-grammar, bnf

Using the grammar rules defined below, I am trying to parse a simple shell command, let's say like `cd testFolder`.

These are my rules defined in parser.y:

```
%union{
    char *str;
}

%type <str> WORD

%%
command_list:/*empty*/
            |command_list command_line{  
                printf("myShell > ");
            }
            ;

arg_list:/*empty*/ 
        | arg_list WORD{
            printf("Args: %s\n", $2);
            free($2);
        }
        ;

cmd_and_args:
             WORD arg_list {
                printf("CMD: %s\n", $1);
                free($1);
             }
            ;

command_line:
            cmd_and_args NEWLINE {printf("NULL\n");
            }
            | NEWLINE {
                printf("NULL\n");
            }
%%
```

So what I wanted the output to be was:

```
CMD: cd
Args: testFolder
NULL
```

but what I get is:

```
Args: testFolder
CMD: cd
NULL
```

For a command like `vim -O test.c test1.c` , I get :

```
Args: -O
Args: test.c
Args: test1.c
CMD: vim
NULL
```

The args are in order, but the command ends up coming last. How do I get them in the right order?

Comment: Why do you care what order they are printed?

Comment: I have to populate a command array, `char **arguments`, so I can pass it to `execvp()` to execute the command. It won't work if they aren't in order.

Comment: It would work fine if you started filling in the args at index 1 and then insert the command into index 0 at the end :-)

Comment: Yeah, I could have done that, but I just wanted to know where I was going wrong in my grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bison produces *bottom-up* parsers, which means that if you think about the parse as a tree, nodes are processed before their parents. (In other words, it's a post-order traverse.)

So the action for

```
 cmd_and_args:  WORD arg_list { … }
```

is executed after the action for `arg_list`.

I don't see why this would be a problem, but you could change it either by using a [Midrule Action](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Midrule-Actions) or by using a unit production to extract the command word.

#### Midrule Action

```
cmd_and_args:  WORD { /* print $1*/ arg_list { /* arg_list is now $3 */ }
```

#### Unit production

```
cmd_and_args: command_word arg_list { … }

command_word: WORD { /* print $1 */ }
```

Note: the grammar does not represent the real shell grammar, which allows assignments to precede the command word (eg. `LC_ALL=C sort file.txt`).

Comment: Ah, the Mid-Rule Action, unfortunately this didn't hit me even when I had read about this in the Bison manual. I think the second grammar, I came up with, uses Unit production. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved this, here's the updated grammar:

```
%union{
    char *str;
}

%type <str> WORD
%%

command_list:/*empty*/
            |com

    mand_list command_line{  
                    printf("myShell > ");
                }
                ;

    command_line: simple_command NEWLINE{
                    printf("NULL\n");
                }
                | NEWLINE{
                    printf("NULL\n");
                }
                ;

    simple_command: simple_command words
                  | WORD{
                    printf("CMD: %s\n", $1);
                  }
                  ;

    words: WORD{
            printf("Args: %s\n", $1);
         }
    %%
```